# asp.net + MS SQL Server: Best Source Control

Tags: sql-server, database, tfs, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I work on a growing web team that needs to adopt a Source Control system. We looked into Source Safe, but were put off by it's lack of SQL Server source control.

The Visual Studio Team System range looks like it does the trick, in terms of source code + database - but I must admit to be confused by the various versions.

So my questions are (from those with experience):

- Is there a free Source Control system that **works well** with asp.net + SQL Server?
- Is VS Team System worth it - for a team of less than five developers?
- Finally - if Team System is the best choice, which edition is the best fit for a small team?

Comment: "We looked into Source Safe, but were put off by it's lack of SQL Server source control." - You can add a database project to your solutions and put your SQL script there. It does work with Source Safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Particularly for a small team, you pretty much can't go wrong with [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org). It's free, open source, and very well supported by the community.

Comment: We have found this to be very easy to use and maintain.

Comment: Is there a good guide for getting started? I'm looking into 'VisualSVN Server' at the moment. At the moment it all feels like a strange new world!

Comment: Although I haven't used that particular version, I understand VisualSVN Server is a good way to get started. Required reading is also Version Control with Subversion, a free online book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com

Comment: Thanks for the link - I shall read this

Comment: We're very pleased with Subversion here at Red Gate, and we use a combination of Tortoise and VisualSVN. You might be interested to know that we're integrating SQL Server source control support into SSMS in our upcoming tool, SQL Source Control. For more info visit http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Comment: Just a note to say that SQL Source Control 1.0 has now been shipped!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people use [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). Place all your SQL into text files and place them in the repository.

Comment: +1 for subversion. Having been using TFS for the last few months, I'm missing subversion so much! Suggest paring it with VisualSVN for a nice Visual Studio Experience

Comment: Very interesting - just posted above about looking into VisualSVN Server. We are using Visual Studio, so it sounds like this will work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, thankfully my company is under 3 years old and we can apply for Biz Spark, which means we get TFS for free. 
I really like TFS, it includes project management, bug tracking and build management as well as version control which is very useful. It also has some database tools built for SQL Server.

If you have the money or Biz Spark go for TFS, if not then take a look at GIT. It's another free source control system that takes a different approach to source control.